# How to create an array of unique_ptrs with custom deleters?

Tags: c++, arrays, unique-ptr, default-constructor, custom-deleter

Here's what I have:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:57,endLineNumber:16,positionColumn:57,positionLineNumber:16,selectionStartColumn:57,selectionStartLineNumber:16,startColumn:57,startLineNumber:16),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%23include+%3Cmemory_resource%3E%0A%23include+%3Cmemory%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring_view%3E%0A%23include+%3Carray%3E%0A%23include+%3Cutility%3E+/*+declval+*/%0A%0A%0Astruct+msg_outbound_t%0A%7B%0A++++std::string_view+hello_+%3D+%22Hello+World!!%22%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A//+Default+deleter+-+works%0A%0A//+using+msg_handle_t+%3D+std::unique_ptr%3Cmsg_outbound_t%3E%3B%0A%0A//+Custom+deleter+-+doesn!%27t+work%0A%0Ausing+allocator_t+%3D+std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator%3Cstd::byte%3E%3B%0A%0Aauto+pmr_deleter(allocator_t+allocator)+%7B%0A++++return+%5Ballocator%5D(msg_outbound_t*+p)+mutable+%7B+allocator.delete_object(p)%3B+%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ausing+msg_handle_t+%3D+std::unique_ptr%3Cmsg_outbound_t,+decltype(pmr_deleter(std::declval%3Callocator_t%3E()))%3E%3B%0A%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++std::array%3Cmsg_handle_t,+8%3E+myarray%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:48.825065274151434,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g122,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Wall+-Os+--std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:41.3677130044843,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:58.632286995515706,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:51.174934725848566,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory_resource>
#include <memory>
#include <string_view>
#include <array>
#include <utility> /* declval */


struct msg_outbound_t
{
    std::string_view hello_ = "Hello World!";
};

// Default deleter - works

// using msg_handle_t = std::unique_ptr<msg_outbound_t>;

// Custom deleter - doesn't work

using allocator_t = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<std::byte>;

auto pmr_deleter(allocator_t allocator) {
    return [allocator](msg_outbound_t* p) mutable { allocator.delete_object(p); };
}

using msg_handle_t = std::unique_ptr<msg_outbound_t, decltype(pmr_deleter(std::declval<allocator_t>()))>;


int main()
{
    std::array<msg_handle_t, 8> myarray;
}
```

It doesn't work as it seems that unique_ptrs with custom deleters can't be default constructed? Is there a workaround to create an array of them?

Errors:

```
<source>:31:33: error: use of deleted function 'std::array<std::unique_ptr<msg_outbound_t, pmr_deleter(allocator_t)::<lambda(msg_outbound_t*)> >, 8>::array()'
   31 |     std::array<msg_handle_t, 8> myarray;
      |                                 ^~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it seems that unique_ptrs with custom deleters can't be default constructed?

Yes, but you'll have to supply a class that it can instantiate as a template parameter:

```cpp
using allocator_t = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<std::byte>;

struct pmr_deleter {
    void operator()(msg_outbound_t * p) {
         allocator.delete_object(p);
    }
    allocator_t allocator;
};

using msg_handle_t = std::unique_ptr<msg_outbound_t, pmr_deleter>;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/h3bqxEnaz)

Comment: Well I was thinking I was doing that by providing a lambda? But now you have left out the closure of the allocator. I get both is not possible? I mean a default constructed unique_ptr wouldn't even have to delete anything so I don't understand why it is deleted in the first place.

Comment: @glades Your `pmr_deleter` lambda requires `allocator` to be captured but there is no `allocator_t` instance in your code. What do you mean by _"now you have left out the closure of the allocator"_? A default constructed `unique_ptr` doesn't call the deleter.

Comment: @glades Do you have any follow-up question or did my answer clear it up?

Comment: Thanks no your answer was very clear. I'm using such an implementation right now,

Comment: Sorry missed that! Accepted now!